# is it possible to maintain chainability in a jQuery plugin and also return true or false

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, chainability

I wrote a beginner jQuery plugin which validate a form.

this jQuery Plugin show an Error under the validating element if it left blank or if it can't pass my regular expression test.

now I want to return true or false from my plugin to disable submit button if the form has an Error.

The question is : Can I do this and also maintain Chainability of my plugin?

I have something like this:

```
$("input[type='text']").change(this.mytextboxvalidator(
{'regex':'something','message':'somethingelse'}));
```

Comment: you aren't chaining your plugin method as it is, without a demo, any answer would be a complete guess

Comment: Writing a brand new jQuery Validation plugin is like opening a hamburger stand next to a steakhouse.  Why?

Comment: @Sparky672 Hi, In my case I should display my errors in specific `<div>` that I have in my form. is there any validation plugin that give regular expression and can show specific message in specific `<div>`?
Thanks

Comment: Yes.   The jQuery Validation plugin gives you all that.  Its "errorPlacement" option facilitates placing the errors anyplace including divs.  And you can use "addMethod" to use any regex you desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you maintain chainabilty, you return a jQuery-object. It's an object, so just add a property to this object where you store the boolean:

```
(function( $ ){

  $.fn.someMethod = function(  ) {  

    var bln=true;
    return (this.each(function() {
      //modify boolean when needed
      bln=false;
    }).extend({myBoolean:bln}));

  };
})( jQuery );
```

Usage:

```
if(!$('someselector').someMethod().myBoolean)
 {
  //disable the button 
 }
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to do so. jQuery method should always return the jQuery (Javascript) object `this`, except in some rare cases. Returning a mixin object like this is confusing, and is a wrong use of jQuery.

Comment: An jQuery-object by default is a very mixed object.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

You **can** do this, but it's a bit controversial :)

<strike>No you can't.</strike> What you should do is write the plugin so that it binds to the change event of the selector.

Inside the plugin you do this to bind to the change event:

```
...
$(this).bind('change', function () {
    //validation logic
});
...    
return this;
```

And you use the plugin like so:

```
$("input[text='text']").mytextvalidator({'regex':'something','message':'somethingelse'});
```

Answer (score 2):

I see a lot of misunderstood here.

First of all, you're not writing a jQuery plugin. A jQuery plugin is used like this:

```
jQuery( ".someSelector" ).myPluginName();
```

You, you're using a method `mytextboxvalidator` passed into a jQuery function `$.fn.change`.

Secondly, as Sparky672 said, you really should consider using an already existing jQuery for form validations, there are tons out there, just Google it.

Thirdly, as I'm a good guy, I'll try to help you with your plugin.

```
// myFormValidationPlugin is the name of your plugin, change it as you want
$.fn.myFormValidationPlugin = function( options ) {

    // bind the event inside the plugin
    this.change(function( ev ) {
        // doing some BASIC verification
        if( options.pattern.test( $(this).val() ) {
            // input is valid
            // in your example, I guess it's here you want to return TRUE
        }
        else {
            // input is invalid
            // in your example, I guess it's here you want to return FALSE
        }
    });


    // NEVER break the chain
    // so yes, you can maintain chainability
    return this;
};

// usage
$( ".someSelector" ).myFormValidationPlugin({
    pattern: /foo/
});
```

I hope this will help. However, this code won't work as you except. To make it work, you should:

1. bind an event to the `submit` event of the form
2. in the handler, check that each element has a valid value
3. if all elements are valid, performs the submit
4. if one or more is invalid, disabled the event for example with `event.preventDefault` call